# After VS2008 to VS2010 project upgrade getting "manifest signing certificate" error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, certificate, manifest

I created a test project with **VS2008 C# Express** on computer 1 (Vista).

I converted it to **VS2010 C# Express** on computer 2 (Windows 7).

The converted project gives me this **error**:

> Unable to find manifest signing
>   certificate in the certificate store.

I've found [articles about signing project certificates](http://www.sqlclr.net/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/9/Default.aspx) etc. but they are not that helpful as **I never explicitly signed any certificates** with this project. It is just a small project (with a MDF database / LINQ-to-SQL) that I created with VS2008 C# Express.

I tried first deleting the **.suo** and the **obj** and **bin** directories of the original project before converting but I still gives the same error.

**How can I stop the converted VS2010 project from trying to find a "manifest signing certificate in the certificate store"?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try disable and re-enable signing:

1. Right click your project
2. Click properties
3. Open the "Signing" tab
4. Uncheck "Sign the assembly"
5. Save with Ctrl-S
6. Check "Sign the assembly" again
7. Save and close

Comment: +1. It also worked in a project I received from somebody else and using Visual Studio 2008 (not Visual Studio 2010).